# Change part of background color of a JFreeChart dynamically?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I was wondering if it was possible to change part of the background of a `JFreeChart` object using `XYPlot` dynamically.

I have a XY plot, and I draw lines from left to right. I want that part, from one point to another, to have a background color different from 3 or 4 previous points.

Answer (score 2):

[`IntervalMarker`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/IntervalMarker.html) "Represents an interval to be highlighted in some way." If you change a marker's values or color, the listening plot will update itself dynamically. Among the examples seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20IntervalMarker), @GrahamA's [`MouseMarkerDemo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16106116/230513) also demonstrates mouse interaction:

[image]